# sqlachemy update value in table doen't update value in associated table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to update a column in a table with a relation one to many.
but i can't figure out a way to make the update impact also the relation table. Here is a sample of the code, i tried to change it with `back_populates`, with or without `onupdate` or `cascade` but it doesn't seem to have any effect on what i want to do

```
class Employe(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'employes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    service_name = Column(String, ForeignKey('services.name', onupdate="CASCADE"))


class Service(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'services'

    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    employers = relationship('Employe', backref=backref('service', cascade="all"))



a = session.query(Service).filter_by(name='ECTC').update({'name' : 'SECTC'})
session.commit()
```

That does change the services.name but let the column service_name untouched.
And so when i want to query `session.query(Employe).filter_by(service_name='SECTC')` i get no result
Is there a way to make the update impact both tables ?
Otherwise i can just select, delete and recreate the employes everytime i need to update services but that doesn't seem optimal to me.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Since your service name is not constant, why not just add an integer primary key to `Service` and use that as the foreign key? This will avoid all data integrity issues.

Comment: hey Ivan, thank you for your answer, this solution seems to work at least for what i've tested so far on my code. I am new to sqlachemy and i didn't know it was hard to modify a foreign key that's why i tried it that way at first but i think i understand now why i see so often an id key on tables !